# Proper syntax highlighting of $...$ in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, latex, preview-latex

I've put

```
(setq org-highlight-latex-and-related '(latex script entities))
```

in my emacs config and yet `$..$` that contain more than one symbol aren't highlighted properly:

> [image]

How to fix?

**EDIT:** This still does not work for me as of `org-version` `9.4`.

Comment: Works for me with org-mode 9.1.13 (9.1.13-elpaplus).

Comment: Evaluating `org-version` yields `9.2.1` for me.

Comment: Did you try `$2+2=4$` without spaces? The notable thing is that LaTeX fragment delimiter `$` are symmetrical unlike `\(` or `\[`. So they have to scan the full expression. Maybe the spaces split the expression.

Comment: Both `$2 + 2 = 4$` and `$2+2=4$` don't highlight, but single characters like `$2$` *do* highlight. Very strange behavior.

Comment: Did you try with `emacs -Q` and maybe `M-x package-initialize`?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I experience the same behaviour, even if I choose `native` highlight instead of `latex`. It seems that it gets confused because in `org-mode` you can insert even currency such as $3500 and .12$.  So it's difficult to distinguish whether and expression is indeed a latex expression or if it's a text inside two monetary values.

If you are using latex I suggest to use the `\( \)` notation, that's why I've never noticed this before.

If you want to dive deep to resolve the issue you can have a look at the function `org-inside-LaTeX-fragment-p` and the variable `org-latex-regexps` defined in `org.el`. Unfortunately it's very complex.